# ruby. Передача хэша параметром метода

Tags: ruby

Расскажите про особенности передачи хеша в методы.
Как я понял,руби может сам "обернуть" хеш,т.е. вместо передачи: **{a:1,b:2}**, можно передать: **a:1,b:2** .Когда хэш последний в списке параметров всё понятно,но что происходит когда есть параметры по умолчанию,массиив,блок.

Answer (score 4):

Одним из применений хэша в качестве аргумента метода является передача поименованых значений к примеру:

```
def mymethod(args)
  n = args[:n] || 0
  m = args[:m] || 0
end

mymethod n:1, m:2 # Одно и 
mymethod m:2, n:1 # тоже

# Начиная с Ruby 2.1 можно делать и так
def mymethod(n:, m:)
  #тело метода
end
```

Если планируете передавать хэш в виде `a:1, b:2` то он будет передан в качестве последнего аргумента если конечно общее количество аргументов соблюдено:

```
def mymethod(a, b, c)
  # Тело метода  
end

mymethod 1, a:1, b:2 # Исключение ArgumentError (представлено 2 аргумента вместо ожидаемых 3-х)
```

Следующий код иллюстрирует передачу обычного аргумента, массива и хэша. В данном случае применение аргументов по умолчанию невозможно.

```
mymethod(a,*b,c)
  puts "#{a.to_s} "+a.class.to_s
  puts "#{b.to_s} "+b.class.to_s
  puts "#{c.to_s} "+c.class.to_s
end

mymethod 1,2,3,b:3,c:4,a:5

####OUTPUT####
1 Fixnum
[2, 3] Array
{:b=>3, :c=>4, :a=>5} Hash
```

Если хотите передать в метод блок,передавайте последним аргументом с аперсандом.

```
mymethod(a,*b,c,&d)
```

Подробнее можно почитать в книге "Язык программирования Ruby" Matz Раздел 6.4.1 и далее.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Прочитал,попрактиковался и вроде разобрался!